# Mysql getting child result from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL which have a column dataid.  if parent have a dataid *abcd* then all child will have dataid as *abcd*.xyz xyz *abcd* is used to denote that this is child of abcd.

currently I am writing this query.

SELECT `comment`.`ID` cid FROM `comment` {Condition} ORDER BY comment.`commentDate` DESC LIMIT 500

Later I fetch the child by running the query that dataid in (all ids) to fetch the childs.

Is there any other way to do this in same query.  MySQL have support for CTE but I am using 5.6 on server. How I can do this in 5.6 MySQL.

Tim point out that I am doing condition wrongly so I have another idea to sort out this issue.

Same table also have parentid, which means I can get all child by running 'where parentid = 5'

Thanks

Comment: How many levels deep is your hierarchy?

Comment: Only one level, child can't have grandchild.

Comment: Show some sample table data, at least including the relevant columns.  I can give you a query, but I need to know what your data is, and you haven't done that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will order by parent followed by all children:

```
SELECT ID, dataid
FROM comment
WHERE ...
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(dataid, '.', 1),    -- sort by group, e.g. abcd
    INSTR(dataid, '.'),                 -- parents before children
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(dataid, '.', -1);   -- sort the children
```

### Demo

Comment: It's take 47 second to run a query on 500000 records, "SELECT ID, dataid
FROM `comment`

ORDER BY
     `commentDate` DESC,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(dataid, '.', 1),
    INSTR(dataid, '.'),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(dataid, '.', -1)
    LIMIT 500"  Please check how to do this on large database

Comment: @Adrian If you want performance, then change your table design and store the parent and child IDs in separate columns.  This is probably as good as it will get given your current design.

Comment: I have a parentid column too, which means if parent id  =5, you can run where parentid= 5 to get all child, I am updating question.